# .net regex number generator using pattern

Tags: .net, string

I have a string like this

```
    "{{A to B}}{{1 to 3}}"
```

It should generate :

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

Note that there could be any number of patterns within the pattern string.

Whats the best way to solve this problem ? Solution preferred in .Net.

Comment: The "regex" tag confuses me - do you just want to list all the possible combinations or convert that into a regex to match any of those combinations or...?

Comment: This cannot be solved by regex.This needs programming.You remove the regex tag

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, it's not possible to resolve this problem using just regex. Here is some code you might find useful:

```
var input = "{{A to B}}{{1 to 3}}{{a to f}}";
var regex = new Regex("\\{\\{((?<p1>[a-z]) to (?<p2>[a-z]))|((?<p1>[A-Z]) to (?<p2>[A-Z]))|((?<p1>\\d) to (?<p2>\\d))\\}\\}");
var groups = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    var start = match.Groups["p1"].Value;
    var end = match.Groups["p2"].Value;

    var group = new List<string>();
    int startValue;
    int endValue;

    if (int.TryParse(start, out startValue) && int.TryParse(end, out endValue))
    {
        for (int i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++)
        {
            group.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var startChar = char.Parse(start);
        var endChar = char.Parse(end);

        for (char c = startChar; c <= endChar; c++)
        {
            group.Add(c.ToString());
        }
    }

    groups.Add(group);
}

var cartesianProduct = groups.CartesianProduct();
var result = cartesianProduct.Select(x => string.Concat(x.ToArray()));

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

To calculate cartesian product I used code from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    foreach (var sequence in sequences)
    {
        var s = sequence;
        result =
            from seq in result
            from item in s
            select seq.Concat(new[] { item });
    }
    return result;
}
```

I missed all checks for valid input, you have to deal with it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

How about for loops? With Regex:

```
    string input = "{{A to B}}{{1 to 3}}";
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\{\{([A-Za-z])\sto\s([A-Za-z])\}\}\{\{([\d])\sto\s([\d])\}\}");
    List<char> rangeChar = new List<char>(){match.Groups[1].Value[0],match.Groups[2].Value[0]};
    List<int> rangeInt = new List<int>() { int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value), int.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value) };

    for (int i =rangeChar.First() ; i<=rangeChar.Last();i++)
        for (int j = rangeInt.First(); j <= rangeInt.Last(); j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((char)i+j.ToString());
        }
```

And without:

```
string input = "{{A to B}}{{1 to 3}}";
string[] inputSplit = input.Split(new[] {@"}{"},StringSplitOptions.None);
List<char> rangeChar = new List<char>();
inputSplit[0].Trim(' ', '{', '}').Split(new[] { "to" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(x => rangeChar.Add(x.Trim()[0]));
List<int> rangeInt = new List<int>();
inputSplit[1].Trim(' ', '{', '}').Split(new[] { "to" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(x=> rangeInt.Add(int.Parse(x)));
for (int i =rangeChar.First() ; i<=rangeChar.Last();i++)
    for (int j = rangeInt.First(); j <= rangeInt.Last(); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((char)i+j.ToString());
    }
```